# Allow only static IP to reach the admin panel

Tags: users

Running Drupal on an Red-Hat instance, how do I configure the server to only allow it's back-end to be reached from a specific static IP?

Comment: Through the web server config would make most sense

Comment: As @Clive says, web server / htaccess way seems simplest. there used to be a module for that: https://www.drupal.org/project/ipAuthenticator but it's old and looks abandoned.